# How to use the Guava ListenableFuture and the Futures.chain() methods

Tags: concurrency, guava, future

I have a homework task that requires me to learn how to use the Guava concurrency library.

In the task I have several thread pools, where each one is controlled by an individual object.

Each pool has several working threads that perform simple tasks (mostly emulating doing stuff by using `Thread.sleep(long)`) and all those simple tasks are stored in a container object that emulates a messageboard.

Each simple task has a dependency list of other tasks, and it cannot be executed until all of those tasks are completed.

How can I benefit from the Guava library using the `ListenableFuture` and the `Futures.chain()`?

I have searched everywhere for some extensive example code online, but didn't find anything that I understand how to use.

Comment: Have you read the [`ListenableFuture` JavaDocs](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html)? They're a good place to start.

Comment: Who is assigning Guava homework?
Also, I should get started on adding explanation of these tools to the Guava wiki.

Comment: @LouisWasserman my university has decided to challenge us. It's actually for extra credit, but I need those extra points. Will do good for my grade. Anyhow, I've read and understood the ListenableFuture API, what I didn't understand is the use of Futures.chain() and how it can aid me in the described scenerio

Comment: It's neat to see Guava being used in an extra credit assignment like this, and it sounds like a useful assignment. It seems to be highlighting something that I'm guessing was a primary motivation for `ListenableFuture` and its related utilities.

Comment: As of Guava version 14 (the version I am currently using) `chain` is no longer part of the library.  It has been replaced with `Futures.transform`

Answer (score 4):

As Louis mentions, I think that `Futures.allAsList` etc. could be useful for you. However, I think that `Futures.chain` *does* seem useful and appropriate for the situation you describe. Since this is an assignment meant to challenge you, I'm not going to say any more than this: `Futures.chain` allows you to submit a task for execution upon completion of another task, and it returns a new `ListenableFuture` representing the result of *that* task. How does that apply to what you're trying to do?

Comment: We should also mention that as of Guava 11, I think Futures.chain is deprecated and Futures.transform(ListenableFuture<A>, AsyncFunction<A, B>) is preferred?  (AsyncFunction<A, B> is basically the same as a Function<A, ListenableFuture<B>>.)

Answer (score 4):

You might be interested in reading the [presentation slides on Guava util.concurrent](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/files/guava-concurrent-slides.pdf), linked on the Guava homepage (slide 11 and onward). They really helped me crystallize my understanding of `ListenableFuture` and why it's so useful.

My guess is that the goal of your assignment is to understand how Futures work, and how Guava's `ListenableFuture` and `Futures.chain()` simplifies their use when coordinating multiple tasks.

The only open source code that comes to mind that uses ListenableFuture is [sitebricks-mail](https://github.com/dhanji/sitebricks/tree/master/sitebricks-mail):

- [MailClient interface](https://github.com/dhanji/sitebricks/blob/master/sitebricks-mail/src/main/java/com/google/sitebricks/mail/MailClient.java)
- [NettyImapClient implementation](https://github.com/dhanji/sitebricks/blob/master/sitebricks-mail/src/main/java/com/google/sitebricks/mail/NettyImapClient.java)

I don't know if it uses `Futures.chain()`, though.

Comment: Unfortunately, a "presentation slides on Guava util.concurrent" link is unavailable :(

Comment: Indeed, it seems they have been removed, since they were outdated: https://github.com/google/guava/issues/2589 I would use this instead: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Futures.chain() is the answer here, if the primary issue is dealing with task dependency lists.  More likely is Futures.allAsList or Futures.successfulAsList, which take multiple futures, and return a future that returns only after all of the input futures have succeeded or failed.

Comment: If http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained doesn't help, by the way, let me know when you do figure it out so I can try to improve that page.