# Java REST - call method after POST to REST

Tags: java, web-services, rest, amazon-web-services

I'm using a Java REST service for a file upload.
The file should land on my server, which it does, then move to Amazon S3 bucket.

The upload to the server is fine, but the 2nd call to another method does not work.
I assume because there is a timeout issue?

The code to move the file to amazon works in another app, but I am not able to get it working within my REST project.

Here is the method:

```
     @POST
     @Path("/upload")
     @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream inputStream,
               @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition file,    @FormDataParam("filename") String filename){

    Logger log = Logger.getLogger("Mike");


    String response = "";
    File f = null;
      try {
       final String FILE_DESTINATION = "C://uploads//" + file.getFileName();
       f = new File(FILE_DESTINATION);
       OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
       int size = 0;
       byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
       while ((size = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(bytes, 0, size);
       }
       outputStream.flush();
       outputStream.close();

       log.info("upload complete for initial file!");
       //move file to Amazon S3 Bucket.
       AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(
                new ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider());

       log.info("trying put request");
       PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest("site.address.org","/pdf/PDF_Web_Service/work/"+f.getName(),f);
        log.info(f.getName());
        log.info(f.getAbsolutePath());

        s3.putObject(request);
        log.info("put request complete");

       response = "File uploaded " + FILE_DESTINATION;
      } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }




      return Response.status(200).entity(response).build();
     }
```

Specifically, here is the part not working. I am not getting any log info either:

```
//move file to Amazon S3 Bucket.
```

> ```
>      AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(
>               new ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider());
>
>      log.info("trying put request");
>      PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest("site.address.org","/pdf/PDF_Web_Service/work/"+f.getName(),f);
>       log.info(f.getName());          log.info(f.getAbsolutePath());
>                   s3.putObject(request);          log.info("put request complete");
> ```

Comment: "I assume because there is a timeout issue?" Why don't you capture the http response code so that you know if that is the issue or not

Comment: @Humdinger I'm a little new to REST. In my code I am explicitly setting the response code to 200. How do I get the "natural" response code?

Comment: When you time-out, you never make it to the return statement. Java automatically sets the time-out code (504) and returns it. If you are getting a 200 back, that means you are getting to the return statement, and timing out is not your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the Amazon code into the try block and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Michael,

If it's a time-out issue, it's common practice to use guava's [Listenable Future](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained) to chain your tasks together. What your web sequence will look like then is:

a) Client sends file

b) Server responds with 200 once file completes uploading.

c) Once the server is done loading the file, [chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626033/how-to-use-the-guava-listenablefuture-and-the-futures-chain-methods) the future to then upload to S3.

Chaining listenable futures is common practice to separate functionality and ensure a time out doesn't occur by breaking up your code and essentially pipe-lining it.

Please let me know if you have any questions!